# Kotlin Android Extension layouts from library module cannot be resolved

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have my `buyer`, `seller` module and a `common` module. Few layouts which are used in both `buyer` and `seller` module are placed in `common` module.

```
common -> layout_toolbar.xml
buyer -> activity_sell.xml ->

<LinearLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" /> <!-- layout_toolbar.xml is from common module -->
</LinearLayout>

seller -> activity_buy.xml ->

<RelativeLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" /> <!-- layout_toolbar.xml is from common module -->
</RelativeLayout>

buyer -> BuyActivity.kt
toolbar.title = "Buy"

seller -> SellActivity.kt
toolbar.title = "Sell"
```

Everything works fine in IDE,

1. My layout preview shows properly by resolving the include tag and inflating in the IDE's layout preview.
2. My kotlin files also properly resolves the toolbar reference and doesn't show any problem.

But whenever I try to build the app, it gives me the compiler error:

```
Unresolved reference: toolbar <-- Id of the toolbar inside layout_toolbar.xml
```

If IDE can resolve the dependencies properly, why can't the gradle build? Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Please note that `common` module is added as `implementation` in other two modules. But I have tried with `api` which doesn't work too.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to a good question at first. I reproduce the same problem in my current project.

1. I have added the library module via

   implementation project(':mylibrary')
2. Added the library module in the project.

[image]

3. Created a layout/view in the library module aka common module.

[image]

4. Included in the main layout

[image]

5. And finally, I am able to change it programmatically.

   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*
   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_library.*

[image]

There might be some problem with the built environment. Note: I am using latest build version and android and kotlin plugins.

Do update your logs for further clarification about your problem.

Comment: Have you built using command line or AS? If AS, can you please try from command prompt.